# unable to dispatch action in redux-toolkit

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I'm trying to understand redux-toolkit. I need to understand why the `Add All Products` button isn't adding all the products to redux store's state. Although `add to cart` is working for individual items. I just want to do the same thing but want to pass all `products` in the argument.

Here is the code:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import React from "react";
import { add } from "./store/cartSlice";
import "./styles.css";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
const Products = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchUsers = async () => {
      const res = await fetch("https://fakestoreapi.com/products");
      const data = await res.json();
      console.log(data);
      setProducts(data);
      // alert(products);
    };
    fetchUsers();
  }, []);

  const handleAdd = (product) => {
    dispatch(add(product));
  };
  const handleAddAll = (products) => {
    dispatch(add(products));
  };
  const items = useSelector((state) => state.cart);
  return (
    <div className="productsWrapper">
      <button onClick={() => handleAddAll(products)}>Add All Products</button>
      <h1>Products List</h1>
      <h3>Cart Size: {items.length}</h3>
      <h3>View Cart: {items.map((item) => item.title)}</h3>
      {products.map((product) => (
        <div className="card" key={product.id}>
          <h4>{product.title}</h4>
          <img src={product.image} alt={product.title} />
          <h4>Price: {product.price}</h4>
          <button onClick={() => handleAdd(product)}>Add to cart</button>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Products;
```

And here is the link to codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/redux-toolkit-listed-trxyrx?file=%2Fsrc%2FProducts.js%3A37%2C35

Comment: In your sandbox you didn't import the `addAll` action even though that's what it was dispatching, so an exception is thrown when clicking the button. After importing `addAll` action the `dispatch(addAll(products));` code in your sandbox seemed to work fine. I don't really understand what the issue or problem is from your end but I don't think this is a valuable post, so voting to close as "Not reproducible or was caused by a typo". Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are pushing an array into an array:

```
add(state, action) {
  state.push(action.payload);
}
```

So if you do:  dispatch(add([product1, product2])) then you will end up with something like this in your state:  [[product1, product2]]

You already have the addAll in your store and that looks right, so use that like:

```
addAll(state, action) {
  return [...state, ...action.payload];
}
```

Comment: RTK uses immer under the hood,  so you do want `state.push` (or similar mutation) vs returning a copy

Comment: @EvanDavis I know  OP mentioned rtk but this is just a redux reducer in which case you dont mutate, see "cartSlice" in the code pen

Comment: OP ***is*** using RTK, so writing a ***mutable*** state update with `state.push` is perfectly valid and acceptable. The issue was due to a typo, either not dispatching the correct `addAll` action in the code snippet in the post, or neglecting to import the `addAll` action they dispatched in the sandbox code.